# Is there a 'max-retries' for Kubernetes Jobs?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

I have batch jobs that I want to run on Kubernetes. The way I understand Jobs:

If I choose `restartPolicy: Never` it means that if the Job fails, it will destroy the Pod and reschedule onto (potentially) another node. If `restartPolicy: OnFailure`, it will restart the container in the existing Pod. I'd consider a certain number of failures unrecoverable. Is there a way I can prevent it from rescheduling or restarting after a certain period of time and cleanup the unrecoverable Jobs?

My current thought for a workaround to this is to have some watchdog process that looks at retryTimes and cleans up Jobs after a specified number of retries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Summary of slack discussion:

No, there is no retry limit. However, you can set a deadline on the job as of v1.2 with `activeDeadlineSeconds`. The system should back off restarts and then terminate the job when it hits the deadline.

Answer (score 13):

FYI, this has now been added as `.spec.backoffLimit`.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

Comment: This should be set as the correct answer